# Issue displaying container background

Tags: html, css

I am working on a inner page, it is http://www.kaniamea.com/fern/inner.html. The background in the container id="inner" does not show up. It broke after I added id="inner-left" and id="inner-right" to the page. id="inner-left is float:left, so when I remove this the background is back but the right panel goes under the left panel which is not what I want. Any idea what might be wrong? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating things takes them out of the normal content flow. As a result the parent container no longer allows for them when working out what height it should take up.

Your parent div with id = "inner" only contains those two divs "inner-left" and "inner-right". So as soon as you float them the parent div is effectively left with no content at all, and therefore no longer needs to take up any height. It therefore reduces to height zero, and it (and it's background) are no longer seen.

One way to fix it is to add another div, inside your parent container but *after* the inner-left and inner-right divs, and in the css give it the property clear:both:-

```
html:  <div class="clearboth"></div>

css:   .clearboth { clear:both };
```

Clear both makes it sit below the two floated divs, and this then forces the parent div to expand to take in this div.

Another way is, in the CSS, to give the parent container the styling: overflow: hidden.

Comment: Thank you GuyH! Your reply was very helpful!